# Store locally a binary file file received as HTTP POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net

I will start by saying that other answers i looked on stackoverflow do not cover the part that fits my problem. Other answer assume you already have access through some variable to the body binary file content of the HTTP POST (so they skip the part that is relevant for me).

I need to save locally a file that I receive as an HTTP POST binary file. I also need to read some values from the HTTP header, but I think I can find a way to do this (I would love if the answer covered this part too).

I am working with a clean C# Web ASP.NET project.

What i want to know is how to access the binary file in the body of an HTML POST that i received so that i can process it and save it locally? I know how to process and save a byte array, i just need to know how to get a reference (as a Stream maybe) to the file in the body.

Here is a sample of the "look" of the code that I expect to reach in the API callback:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public string Post( /* do i need this?-> [FromBody] SomeModel value */)
    {
        /*
            -- I read some key:value pairs from the header --
            
            var val_1 = HeadersHere.getSpecificKey("name1");   
            var val_1 = HeadersHere.getSpecificKey("name2");   
            var val_1 = HeadersHere.getSpecificKey("name3");   

            -- But i need to also store locally a binary file sent in the http body --
            
            Stream s = SomeCodeHere.body.toStreamSomeHow();

            MyRoutineThatStoresTheFile("filename.dat", s);
        */

        return "Some Ok code";
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. If you do a quick search for "C# mvc file upload", you will find several good examples (top of this screen: "Search").

Comment: Answer found here:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Save-file-to-Server-Folder-Disk-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Here is what i needed:                   
`byte[] data = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`